# hardcoded string “Image”, should use @string resource

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

Hi everyone its me again i am currently developing android app. I am using eclipse classic, i have difficulties when i put ImageView in my main.xml layout there was an error message saying hardcoded string “Button”, should use @string resource. What I did is I open the string.xml Do i need to put the image source before the closing tag?.

I am trying to do the implicit intents in my project.
The output of this app is when i open the gallery then I click one of the pictures uploaded in my virtual device when I click share there are options that can handle that events. Example when I click share I have "facebook, tweeter options." something like that.

BTW thanks everyone I learn a lot from you guys.

Comment: post the relevant parts of your main.xml and string.xml

Comment: Is it an actual error(red), or just a warning(yellow)? You can compile and run with hard-coded strings. It's just trying to remind you to use  xml strings for best practice purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem has anything to do with the ImageView source. The problem is that you are using a hard-coded string in your xml instead of which you can put it in strings.xml in the following way:

```
<string name="stringId">The actual string value</string>
```

And when retrieving it in your xml you can use @string/stringId

I hope you find a solution. In case you don't, kindly paste your code here so that we can get the complete idea of what you are trying to do.